# How to build contact form from scratch (no plugin)

Tags: craft3, form

I want to build a simple contact form without plugin, i am new to craft cms coming from wordpress, how can i build a simple form that will be save on entries and will send an email.

Comment: What is your major objection to plugins? You could build the entire thing for free in an hour using [Contact Form](https://plugins.craftcms.com/contact-form) and [Contact Form Extensions](https://plugins.craftcms.com/contact-form-extensions), or you could spend a week (or more) reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s an example of how you can do exactly that using only the CraftQL plugin: [Using Vue.js + GraphQL to make Practical Magic](https://nystudio107.com/blog/using-vuejs-graphql-to-make-practical-magic)

You can also do it with a frontend Entry form without any any plugins at all, and without JavaScript or GraphQL: [Craft CMS Entry Form Example](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/entry-form.html)

And in general can do a whole lot without plugins: [Cutting was he Cord: Removing Craft CMS 3 Plugins](https://nystudio107.com/blog/cutting-the-cord-removing-plugins)